# Why does JavaScript return an array of node names and not node HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to see if a radio button is checked and if so, to set each radio button in the group to have an attribute "data-set" set to true.

Looking at my code, I am looping through each input, looking for any with the attribute of "radio" and then seeing if it is checked or not. If one of the inputs is checked then I want to set the dataset set to true for both elements that have the same name attribute.

The problem is that when I traverse up into the parent node and then view the children, I get an array of nodes such as `[input#male, input, male: input, gener: input#male]` instead of getting an array of HTML DOM elements such as `[<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/>,<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/>]`.

Later, I try to see if these children elements are checked, however, these return undefined. I presume that this is because JS is returning name references instead of the actual HTML elements. Am I interpreting this correctly?

Below is an example, with self.inputs being the group of all inputs in the row, of how I traverse the DOM elements after looping through each input in the form row.

```
if ( self.inputs[a].length > 1) {
    //if there are a group in inputs such as input = text then go through
    //each one and see if it is empty or has a value
    for ( b = 0; b <= self.inputs[a].length -1; b++) {
         //if a radio button is checked then all other radio buttons with the same name
        //need to have the data-set value to true
        if ( self.inputs[a][b].getAttribute('type') == 'radio' ) {
           if (self.inputs[a][b].checked == false) {
            } else {
              //if the radio button is checked then make sure that all named grouped items are set to true
              var name = self.inputs[a][b].getAttribute('name');
              var this_parent = self.inputs[a][b].offsetParent; 
              console.log( this_parent.childNodes[0].checked);
              var this_children = this_parent.getElementsByTagName('input');
              console.log( this_children);  
           }
        } else { 
        //if the form element has a value then we need to set the data-set to true; 
            self.inputs[a][b].setAttribute('data-set', true); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your relative `html` also

Comment: where does `self.inputs[a]` come from?

Comment: Your code retuns an array of HTML DOM elements (including text nodes of course) So your code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that when I traverse up into the parent node and then
>   view the children, I get an array of nodes such as [input#male, input,
>   male: input, gener: input#male] instead of getting an array of HTML
>   DOM elements such as [,].

Thats because you are using `this_parent.childNodes[0]` , which as the name suggests will return node.

If you want to get the element, use `this_parent.children[0]`

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Netdeamon/2sf17354/)